# How to use to use assert in Selenium WebDriver for lists

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, assert

I am trying to verify the months displayed on the Facebook login page using Assert.

However, the output I am getting is not correct.

Here is the code:

```
public class DropDown3 {

    @Test
    public void selectByvalue() throws InterruptedException{

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        WebElement month_dropdown= driver.findElement(By.id("month"));
        Select month_dd = new Select(month_dropdown);

        List<WebElement> month_list = month_dd.getOptions();
        int total_months = month_list.size();
        System.out.println("Total month Count is = " + total_months);

        String[] exp = {"Month", "JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"};

        for (WebElement ele: month_list) {
            for(int i=0; i<exp.length; i++) {
                if(ele.getText().equals(exp[i])) {
                    System.out.println("Matched ");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use the following code below**

```
public class DropDown3 {

    @Test
    public void selectByvalue() throws InterruptedException {

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        List<WebElement> months = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//select[@id = 'month']/*"));
        int total_months = months_list.size();
        System.out.println("Total month Count is = " + total_months);

        String[] exp = {"Month", "JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"};

        int count = 0;
        for (WebElement ele: months) {
            count++;
            Assert.assertTrue(ele.getText().toLowerCase().equals(exp[count].toLowerCase) {

            System.out.println("Matched ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code snippet:

```
for(int count =0 ; count < month_list.size(); count++)
{
    WebElement ele = month_dd.getOptions().get(count);
    System.out.println(ele.getText());
    for(int i=0; i<exp.length; i++)
    {
        if(ele.getText().toLowerCase().equals(exp[i].toLowerCase()))
        {
            System.out.println("Matched ");
        }
    }
}
```

FYI: Fetched values for options with id: month are as below - **Month, Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sept, Oct, Nov, Dec**

You can remove the .toLowerCase() function if you want to compare the actual string.

Comment: Only "Sept" with four letters?

Comment: A Facebook quirk?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the below code snippet in your code:

```
WebElement month_dropdown= driver.findElement(By.id("month"));
Select month_dd = new Select(month_dropdown);
List<WebElement> month_list = month_dd.getOptions();
int total_months = month_list.size();
System.out.println("Total month Count is = " + total_months);
String[] exp = {"Month", "JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"};

for (int i=0; i<total_months; i++)
{
    // Use Assertion you yow want to abort execution if value is not expected
    //assertEquals(month_list.get(i).getText().toUpperCase(), exp[i].toUpperCase());

    if (month_list.get(i).getText().equalsIgnoreCase(exp[i]))
    {
        System.out.println("Matching value: " + month_list.get(i).getText() + " : : " + exp[i]);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Non-matching value: " + month_list.get(i).getText() + " : : " + exp[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to take care of a couple of things as follows:

1. The Firefox browser opens in maximized mode, so you can eliminate `driver.manage().window().maximize();`
2. You are storing the `month_dd.getOptions();` in a `List<WebElement>`, so to later to compare the values better, we use a `List<String>` instead of a `String[]` array.
3. Initialize a single iterator to traverse both `List`s.
4. While comparing text, instead of `equals` use `equalsIgnoreCase` which will take care of the case sensitiveness.
5. Here is your own code with some simple tweaks:

   ```
   public class Assert_List
   {
       @Test
       public void selectByvalue() throws InterruptedException
       {
           System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
           WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
           driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
           WebElement month_dropdown = driver.findElement(By.id("month"));
           Select month_dd = new Select(month_dropdown);
           List<WebElement> month_list = month_dd.getOptions();
           System.out.println("Total month_list Count is = " + month_list.size());
           List<String> month = Arrays.asList("Month", "JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC");

           for(int i=0; i<month_list.size(); i++)
           {
               if(month_list.get(i).getText().equalsIgnoreCase(month.get(i)))
                   System.out.println("Matched");
               else
                   System.out.println("Didn't match");
           }
       }
   }
   ```

The Console Output is as follows:

````
Total month_list Count is = 13
Matched
Matched
Matched
Matched
Matched
Matched
Matched
Matched
Matched
Didn't Match
Matched
Matched
Matched
PASSED: selectByvalue

===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```lang-none

Note: On page `https://www.facebook.com/`, the month is *Sept* whereas our `List` contains *SEP*. Hence, it *didn't match*.
````

Answer (score 0):

You could use the collection, if you don't want to use too many loops.

First convert the String array to `ArrayList`. And create a new list which contains the *expected* `ArrayList`:

```
List<String> months = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Month", "JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"));
List<String> actualMonths = new ArrayList<String>();

List<WebElement> month_list = month_dd.getOptions();
for (WebElement ele: month_list){
    actualMonths.add(ele.getText());
}
```

If order does not matter, apply sort on both the lists. If order matters, you don't even need to apply sort.

```
Collections.sort(months);
Collections.sort(actualMonths);
Assert.assertTrue(months.equals(actualMonths));
```